# How to use reactiveElements inside data.frame()

Tags: r, dataframe, random-forest, prediction, shinydashboard

I have imported my datasets into my app.R . There is a problem in adding the user inputs to the dataframe and how to get the output as Yes or No after prediction and display the output after using predict()
this is my ui dashboad body:

```
     box(mainPanel("ENTER THE DETAILS :",br(),br(),textInput("name","Name :","Name Here"),br(),
                                                numericInput("uiage",'Age :',value = 25,min = 25,max = 100),br(),
                                                 radioButtons("uigender","Gender :",c("Male","Female"),inline=TRUE),br(),
                                                textInput("uipurpose","Purpose Of Loan :","Car Loan"),br(),
                                                numericInput("uicredhist",'Cibil Score :',min=1,max=10,value = 9),br(),
                                                numericInput("uicredamt", 'Credit Amount',value = 10000),br(),
                                                numericInput("uicommitment","Intallment Commitment",value =2,min=0,max=6),br(),
                                                radioButtons("uiemplymentstatus","Employment Status :",c("Yes","No"),inline = TRUE),br(),br(),
                                                numericInput("uicheckingstatus",'Checking Status :',min=1,max=10,value = 9),br(),
                                                textInput("uipropmag","Property Magnitude:","real-estate/life-insurance/car/jewels"),br(),
                                                radioButtons("uihousing","Housing :",c("own","rent"),inline = TRUE),br(),
                                                radioButtons("uiforeign","Foreign Worker :",c("yes","no"),inline=TRUE),br(),
                                                radioButtons("uieducation","Educational Qualities :",c("Skilled","Un-Skilled"),inline = TRUE),br(),
                                            actionButton("submit",label = "Submit"),textOutput("text1")))


This is my server logic to get user inputs :

    text_reactive1 <- eventReactive( input$submit, {
    userage <- input$uiage
  })


    text_reactive2 <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    usercredithist <- input$uicredhist
  })



    text_reactive3 <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    usercredamt <- input$uicredamt
  })


    text_reactive4 <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    usercommit <- input$uicommitment
  })

this is my algorithm :


    fit <- randomForest(df$class~df$age+df$credit_history+df$credit_amount+df$installment_commitment, data=datfr$df)

 randpred <-reactive({ predict(fit,dframe=data.frame(text_reactive1(),text_reactive2(),text_reactive3(),text_reactive4()))})

  output$text1 <- renderText({
  paste("Input cred hist is :",randpred())
  })
```

I need my output as Yes or no .. can somebody help me solve this..

[image]

Comment: What constitutes a "yes" and what constitutes a "no". is it if the `predict` function is above a certain threshold? if so, add an `ifelse` statement.
Additionally, if you want to you can condense your server logic with `observeEvent` and store the inputs into reactive values.

Comment: Not by comparing the threshold but by viewing at the previously loaded data sets values and it should give the output only using the user inputs which i am getting through dashboard "age,credit history, credit amount , installment commitment) how to train only these attributes and how to get the prediction in as to whether "WE CAN GIVE LOAN TO THE PARTICULAR PERSON --->YES" or "NOT AN ELIGIBLE PERSON TO APPLY FOR LOAN ---->NO "..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things going on with this question and not very much of it is clear.

I'm assuming these are the following problems you need help with

1. Applying Random Forests Correctly
2. Accessing input values from `shiny`

## Random Forests

A lot of what is wrong with your code is using the incorrect arguments, since you did not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of data, I will continue with the `iris` dataset.

```
fit <- randomForest(formula = Species~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length,
                    data = iris)
```

when you call `randomForest` with formula notation, you do not need to (and probably shouldn't) access the vectors with `$` but instead use their symbol names. This is mostly a distinction with using `predict` on new data.

`predict`'s argument to test your model on new data is `newdata` *not* `dframe`. Since `dframe` is never evaluated (because of lazy evaluation), the default of the `predict` function just returns the values of the original predicted values. I'm going to circle back to your predicted values in a second, but first I want to show what you need to do
with `newdata` argument.

```
#If I did random forests accessing vectors with $
dim(iris)
#[1] 150   5
fit <- randomForest(formula = iris$Species~iris$Sepal.Width+iris$Sepal.Length,
                    data = iris)
predict(fit) # default returns predicted values
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(Sepal.width = c(1:10), Sepal.Length = c(21:30)) #throws an error
#Error in x[...] <- m : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
#In addition: Warning message:
#'newdata' had 10 rows but variables found have 150 rows
```

Because the `randomForest` `formula` argument was given a vector of length 150, it expects the new dataframe to be that size. This is still an issue though because even if `newdata` dimensions are satisfied, the fit is almost always the same...

```
test1 <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(rnorm(150,2194192,409), rnrom(150, -12359,21885999)))
test2 <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(rnorm(150, 10000),rnorm(150, -1000000)))
all(test1==test2)
#TRUE
```

Using the correct notation, then :

```
fit <- randomForest(formula = Species~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length,
                    data = iris)
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(Sepal.Width = 1:10, Sepal.Length = 10:1))
#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
#virginica virginica virginica virginica    setosa    setosa    setosa    setosa    setosa    setosa 
#Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

**Note**: the `newdata` data frame must have the same column headers as the response values in your `randomForest` fit, otherwise you will get an error.

Now I want to talk about your predictive variable. Since you have not provided a sample of what your data looks like I am assuming `df$class` is your what you are trying to classify. Since your `predict` output is providing you with a number - I'm guessing `df$class` is either a continuous value or stored as a integer of `0` or `1`.
If you wish to have `randomForest` return either a `"yes"` or a `"no"`, then `df$class` should be a factor vector containing either `"yes"` or `"no"`.

## Server logic

Again, I don't know for sure if there are any errors in the code you presented because there is not reproducible example, but I would condense your server logic as such.

```
server <- function(input, output){
#somewhere load and assign datfr
fit <- randomForest(class~age+credit_history+credit_amount+installment_commitment,
                    data=datfr$df)
rv <- reactiveValues(userage = NULL,
                     usercredithist = NULL,
                     usercredamt = NULL,
                     usercommit = NULL)
observeEvent(input$submit,{
    req(input$uiage, input$uicredhist, input$uicredamt, input$uicommitment)
    rv$userage <- input$uiage
    rv$usercredithist <- input$uicredhist
    rv$usercredamt <- input$uicredamt
    rv$usercommit <- input$uicommitment
    }
)

randpred <-reactive({
    predict(fit,
            newdata=data.frame(age=rv$userage,
                               credit_history=rv$usercredithist,
                               credit_amount=rv$usercredamt,
                               installment_commitment=rv$usercommit))
})

output$text1 <- renderText({
    paste("Input cred hist is :",randpred())
})
```

Comment: Thank You It's is predicting  but i am getting my output in the form of thershold values .. As you have mentioned above , "If you wish to have randomForest return either a "yes" or a "no", then df$class should be a factor vector containing either "yes" or "no". " How to change this .. my df$class has 0's and 1's how to change it to "yes" or  "no" .. is there any easy way to display the output in yes or no format..

Comment: If we are assuming that 0 is "no" and 1 is "yes", the one liner you could run to convert the values could be:. `df$case <- factor(ifelse(df$case==1,"yes","no"), levels =c("yes","no"))`

Comment: I got the Output.. Thank you so much for the Timely help . It means a lot to me .I was struggling for the past two days on this problem .. Your Detailed description helped me in solving my problem. Once again Thank You so much

Comment: If you need your data to be in this format, then you should consider cleaning your data either before you load it into `r` or directly after reading it into a variable. I don't know anything about your project or program other than what you have previously posted, and I personally believe I left a detailed explanation already. I encourage you to read some documentation and do a bit more trial and error. There are a bunch of open source tutorials that cover the topics you seem to be struggling with. Best of luck.

Comment: I am new to this R and shiny and i am learning it and I'll definitely continue... and I got it cleared from sources. Thanks a lot..